# Object pointer randomly points to 0x00000

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tinyxml

I'm running a Visual C++ MFC application in release mode.  I'm compiling everything using Visual Studio 2010.

My app runs a mini CNC mill through USB VCP communication.

I have a XML file that stores the app's settings.

My problem is this: ocassionaly (and this is repeatable) the pointer to the tinyxml2::XMLDocument I'm using gets set to 0x000.

Info:

Occasionally, the XML file get written to while the mill is running.

Before the error happens, the mill I'm running siezes for almost 30 seconds.

I'm using mutex locks to make sure the xmldoc doesn't get written to file twice at once.

The mutex locks are working, and the mutex error never occurs.  I know the mutex code isn't perfect, but that isn't the issue.  Honest.

I never write to the xmldoc pointer except when the parent class is booting up.

And then, all of a sudden, the xmlDoc pointer gets set to zero.

Any thoughts anyone?

Here is my saving code, although the problem may lie elsewhere:

```
void XMLSettings::SaveToXML()
{
    HANDLE g_Mutex = CreateMutex( NULL, TRUE, "XMLSavingMutex");
    DWORD wait_success = WaitForSingleObject( g_Mutex, 30000L);
    if(wait_success == WAIT_OBJECT_0){
        CIsoProApp* pApp = (CIsoProApp*)AfxGetApp();
        if(PathFileExists(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\temp.xml"))
        {
            DeleteFile(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\temp.xml");
        }

        if(0==&xmlDoc)
        {
            OutputDebugString("xmlDoc == NULL");
        }

        int errorcode = xmlDoc->SaveFile(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\temp.xml");

        if(errorcode != 0)
        {
            OutputDebugString("xmlDoc == errorcode");
        }

        if(0==&xmlDoc)
        {
            OutputDebugString("xmlDoc == NULL2");
        }

        if(0==xmlDoc)
        {
            OutputDebugString("xmlDoc == NULL");
        }

        if(PathFileExists(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\Settings.xml"))
        {
            DeleteFile(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\Settings.xml");
        }
        MoveFile(pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\temp.xml",pApp->DrivePath + "IsoPro\\Settings.xml");
        ReleaseMutex(g_Mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        int errorInt = GetLastError();
        CString error;
        error.Format("%d",errorInt);
        if(errorInt != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            AfxMessageBox("XMLSavingMutex Error.  WaitSuccess = " + wait_success);
            AfxMessageBox("XMLSavingMutex Error.  GetLastError = " + error);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(g_Mutex);
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple threads calling `SaveToXML` perhaps you should make the mutex `static`. Also, what version of visual studio are you using? We can use more standardized thread synchronization features here.

Comment: As AndyG said - you don't want to be creating / destroying the mutex, you need a single instance that you lock & unlock.

Comment: You could set up a data breakpoint in the Visual Studio. So you could find when exactly your pointer invalidates.

Comment: Pretty cool application, though.

Comment: I saw that you're using Visual Studio 2010, so it looks like you're fine with using windows specific thread synchronization.

Comment: @AndyG No reason it shouldn't be static that I can see, but that it is *not* is likely one reason the OP is using a *named* mutex., They should be able to [`CreateMutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx) with same-name and, so long as permissions allow, get back a waitable closable handle. In short, the mutex code, at least from where I'm looking, *should* work. However, since nothing *here* changes that txml ptr, and we have no idea whether the code that *does* uses this same named mutex, this proc seems odd to try and analyze.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Good point. OP if you go this route, note that the second argument to `CreateMutex` should be `FALSE`

Comment: @AndyG The routine is called every 150ms when there is no new writing going on.  Its called FROM a static routine that call AfxGetApp().  The AfxGetApp has a variable that points to an instance of my XMLSettings class.  The WaitForSingleObject routine takes care of the mutex running the same code twice at the same time.  Have I missed something?

Comment: @Ari0nhh I tried creatging a data breakpoint, but then messageboxes started popping up all over the place.  I'll post more soon.

Comment: @AndyG How is the second argument being TRUE hurting me.  If its an issue, shouldn't it throw an error during the first 100 saves?

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you are creating a Mutex *each time* `SaveToXML` is called, you should change your call to

```
HANDLE g_Mutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, "XMLSavingMutex");
```

Doing this will create a named mutex that allows the implementation to dictate who the owner is; other threads will receive the same mutex.

From the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Two or more processes can call `CreateMutex` to create the same named mutex. The first process actually creates the mutex, and subsequent processes with sufficient access rights simply open a handle to the existing mutex. This enables multiple processes to get handles of the same mutex, while relieving the user of the responsibility of ensuring that the creating process is started first. When using this technique, you should set the `bInitialOwner` flag to `FALSE`; otherwise, it can be difficult to be certain which process has initial ownership.

(Credit to WhozCraig for pointing out named mutexes)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the WaitForSingleObject routine keeps multiple mutexes from running the "synchronized" code.  Have I missed something?

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` is going to try to lock the mutex. If each thread has its own mutex, then there's really no point.

Comment: @DanG: There's also the possibility that the error is in code you haven't shown us yet. I'm sure `xmlDoc` gets passed around and used in other contexts than this.

Comment: I'm looking into that and will report back with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was accessing the xml getter while writing the xml to a file.  I put a single mutex lock in place for all xml actions and things seem to be functioning properly.  Thanks to everyone for their help.  I'll be in touch with more info if it becomes available.